# How do I make a stop effect in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I do not speak English I apologize for this.

I'm new to Unity 3d.

It's my responsibility. I want the objet to stop at another object, then continue. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add colliders and RigidBodies to the objects. Add a script to the box, and in the `OnCollisionEnter` function mark the box as `isKinematic` in the RigidBody component, and at the same time start a coroutine to wait for 3 seconds. After 3 seconds set `isKinematic` back to false.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(!collidedWithOtherObject) {
        collidedWithOtherObject = true;

        this.GetComponent<RigidBody>().isKinematic = true;
        this.StartCoroutine(SetKinematic_Coroutine);
    }
}

IEnumerator SetKinematic_Coroutine() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    this.GetComponent<RigidBody>().isKinematic = false;
}
```